# Imported FormsModule but still No value accessor for form control [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, binding, ngmodel, two-way-binding

Shared Module imports/exports FormsModule. I have used two way binding `[(ngModel)]` in many components and works as usual, but in certain component everytime I try to do exactly the same binding, there appears error: "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

`<img [src]="defaultImage" alt="Chosen Img" [(ngModel)]="data.id">`

I tried on `img`'s parent `div` tag and still - same error.

It seems so strange for me that other sibling components work perfectly. Does anyone have any idea why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because an image is not a form control.

See form controls as inputs : you can write things in them, or change their state (radio buttons, checkboxes, etc)

For what you are trying to achieve, I guess the syntax is

```html
<img [src]="defaultImage" alt="Chosen Img" [id]="data.id">
```